# Formatting "key: value" strings with middle spaces

Tags: python-3.x, format

I'm showing key-value pair in a QListWidget. Since key names have different lengths, numbers start in different positions:

```
TestParameter1: 1.2345
Param2: 6.7890
```

If it wasn't for the key name, I know that I can use format to introduce spaces with a syntax like `'{:7.4f}'.format(value)`.

Is there any easy way (I mean, not switching to a table or creating my own implementation os a QListView) of achieving something like...?:

```
TestParameter1: 1.2345
Param2:         6.7890
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you take a further look at string formatting [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax).

The first thing that comes to mind is to either use the `\t` (tab) to align as necessary; or to use something on the lines of the below as stated in the python docs.

```
>>> for align, text in zip('<^>', ['left', 'center', 'right']):
...     '{0:{fill}{align}16}'.format(text, fill=align, align=align)
...
'left<<<<<<<<<<<<'
'^^^^^center^^^^^'
'>>>>>>>>>>>right'
>>>
```